# Axios' then() call to external function cannot get data

Tags: axios

```
  methods: {
    getHomeInfo() {
      axios.get("/js/index.json").then(this.getHomeInfoSucc());
      //err：undefined
      axios.get("/js/index.json").then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
      //Data available
    },
    getHomeInfoSucc(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
```

#### I used Axios in Vue to use the anonymous function in Axios's then () to get data, but in then (), I call the function in methods to get the response data undefined

Comment: Try this : 
axios.get(`/js/index.json`).then(res => {
   console.log(res.data);
   this.getHomeInfoSucc(res));
  });

Comment: The problem is solved thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback:

```
methods: {
    getHomeInfo() {
      axios.get("/js/index.json").then((res) => this.getHomeInfoSucc(res));
      //err：undefined
      axios.get("/js/index.json").then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
      //Data available
    },
    getHomeInfoSucc(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If my response helps you with founding the solution you should thank me by approving the response!!!